# replacement not working properly in livecode

Tags: livecode

Iam using this code for replacing, but in some instance(begining of the line where there is no space). How to overcome this?
Shall we use regular expression (\n\|\s) in that code?

put the htmlText of field "myTextField"" into myHtml
set the caseSensitive to true
replace " re" with " sa" in myHtml
set the htmlText of fld "myTextField" to myHtml

Comment: Please format your code to make it easier to read. Use the { } icon at the top of the composition area.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking. Can you be more specific or provide examples?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want instances of "re" changed at the beginning of a word, try looping through each word, test whether if begins with "re" and change accordingly:

```
    repeat with i = 1 to the number of words in myHtml
      if char 1 to 2 of word i of myHtml = "re" then replace "re" with "sa" in word i of myHtml 
    end repeat
```

Note: the reason I'm not using 'repeat for each' is that you can't make changes to the thing being parsed in 'repeat for each'

Comment: Is it possible to use regular expressions in livecode.

Comment: i want to transpose (sam)(123). i want to transpose this by \2\1, means 123sam. Is this possible to use \2 and \1?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use \2\1 in LiveCode!

Comment: Hi - you can use regular expressions in LiveCode - look for 'matchtext' in the LC dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest solution is to do a double replace

```
 replace " re" with " ha" in field "myTextField"
 replace return & "re" with return & "ha" in field "myTextField"
```

There is a replaceText which lets you use regular expressions but then you can't use \1 in LiveCode so you will end up replacing all your whitespace with the same character. If that is OK you can use:

```
put replaceText(field "myTextField", "\sre", " ha") into field "myTextField"
```

Comment: How to pass values through variable instead of specific value ("\sre")

Comment: put replaceText(field "myTextField", "\sre", " ha") into field "myTextField". I need to replace \sv( v is a variable have some value)